# I would like to add with tags when POSTing to Facebook from an iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have successfully posted now.  I have successfully set the privacy params and they work fine.  Next, I would like to be able to add people tags like you can do in the Facebook website, where it adds to your message such as:  with Bill Smith and Joe Blow.  I've read the documentation on Post's.  There it includes an item called message_tags, but that seems to refer to a location in the message.  So, I created a message on the FB website on my wall where I added a couple of friends and the message has the 'with x and y' on the screen.  Then, in my app, I downloaded my posts to see what they looked like in the logging view.  No message_tags, but two other places, 'to'  and 'with_tags' have the friends there.  So, I modified my posting code to use each of these and even tried using both.  They post with no error, but viewing on the FB website, no mention of the friends.
When I download these posts using my app, no mention of 'to' or 'message_tags' or 'with_tags'.
Any help would be appreciated.

In addition, I have tried to specify a place in the params.  I used data taken from a post which I created on the FB website and downloaded into my app, so the data should be valid. Here is the JSON:
place = "{\"id\":\"171321908789\",\"name\":\"City O City\",\"location\":{\"street\":\"206 E. 13th Ave.\",\"longitude\":\"-104.9845\",\"latitude\":\"39.7367\",\"zip\":\"80203\"}}";

When I include this for key: place,  I get this:
    0 : {contents = "message"} = {contents = "(#100) {"id":"171321908789","name":"City O City","location":{"street":"206 E. 13th Ave.","longitude":"-104.9845","latitude":"39.7367","zip":"80203"}} does not resolve to a valid user ID"}

Comment: Is nobody posting and including location and with_tags?  I still cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

To post

```
Hi -- in PLACE with FRIEND1 and FRIEND2
```

you only need the ids of the place and friends. Try the following parameters :

```
message : "Hi",
place : "PLACE-id",
tags : "FRIEND1-id, FRIEND2-id"
```

It works for me in the graph explorer (
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with the publish_actions permissions, when I post to https://graph.facebook.com/ME-id/feed

Hope it helps some people and is not too late for you.
A.